# Is await bcrypt.hash() the same as bcrypt.hashSync()?

Tags: node.js, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, bcrypt

With regards to the [bcrypt npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt), I see that the async version is recommended. However, I would like to truly understand the differences between both versions in terms of performance (i.e. event loop, blocking I/O, etc.)

Version 1: Async

```
const hash = await bcrypt.hash(...)
...
```

Version 2: Sync

```
const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(...)
...
```

In other words, if i'm calling `bcrypt.hash` with `await`, are the effects equal to the sync version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sync vs async versions differ in that they use the underlying sync vs async salt generation. So async entropy gathering.

https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/blob/7a720bd2e5450f97e64d4a1d4ac23190b1417c65/bcrypt.js#L30
https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/blob/7a720bd2e5450f97e64d4a1d4ac23190b1417c65/bcrypt.js#L76

Then the hashing is offloaded to a worker thread for the async hash.

https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/blob/aac593c3922253c732bb62197913a26a8302fbe6/src/bcrypt_node.cc#L216
https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/blob/aac593c3922253c732bb62197913a26a8302fbe6/src/bcrypt_node.cc#L241

So yes it does make a different to use async and will avoid blocking the node event loop

Answer (score 2):

I do not know about how exactly bcrypt implemented it, but if it is recommended and it is truly fully async, it means they do it in different thread and it does not block the main thread.

In Node.js, event loop and all code you write is in one thread - once you start doing something, the synchronous part has to be first fully executed which means everything else is blocked.
You dont want to block your REST API for responding, right? Each milisecond counts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bcrypt.hash() and make it asynchronous like so:

```
bcrypt.hash(password,saltRounds).then(hash)=>{

//run whatever you want here once the operation has completed, such as creating your user
}
```